# What is the use of "and not" in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

why does the code not work without the "and not found". What is the use of this statement?

```
def BinarySearch(alist, item):
  first=0
  last=len(alist)-1
  found=False  
  while first<=last and not found: 
    midpt= (first+last)//2
    if alist[midpt] == item:
      found=True
    else:
      if item < alist[midpt]:
        last=midpt-1
      else:
        first=midpt+1
  return(found)

alist=[1,2,3,4,5]
item=8
print(BinarySearch(alist,item)
```

)

Comment: The best way to understand this sort of thing (other than reading) is to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement. If you do that with and without the `and not found`, and you change `item` from `8` to `3` in your test usage above, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Both `first <= last` and `not found` must be true; it's just a boolean expression. There is no `and not` construct here.

Comment: The code is overly complicated by using a `found` flag; you could remove `and not found`, replace `found = True` with `return True`, and `return(found)` with `return False`.

Comment: Last but not least, it is [reinventing the bisect wheel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html); the standard library module implements bisection in C code, all that is needed is `pos = bisect.bisect(alist, item)`, then `return pos < len(alist) and alist[pos] == item`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a statement, it's an expression (three expressions*, really).

If you remove the `and not found` part, the search will not stop when it finds the item, it will keep going until it reaches the end. With the `and not found`, it stops when it finds the item.

In your case, since you're looking for something in the list that won't be found (`8`), it doesn't make any difference. But if you look for, say, `3`, it will.

---

* Unnecessary detail:

1. Accessing a variable is an expression that results in the value the variable contains, so the `found` in `and not found` is an expression.
2. `not v1` (where *v1* is the value from #1) is the second expression: It takes the given value and negates it.
3. `v0 and v2` (where *v2* is the value from #2 and *v0* is the result of the expression before `and not found`) is the third expression: Its result is true when both of its operands are true, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`found` is a boolean flag to indicate whether you've found the item you've been looking for. Once you've found it, there's no point to continue looking for it, and you should just return it.

An arguably neater implementation would be to use the early-return paradigm and just return `True` once the item is found:

```
def BinarySearch(alist, item):
  first = 0
  last = len(alist) - 1
  while first<=last: 
    midpt = (first+last)//2
    if alist[midpt] == item:
      return True

    if item < alist[midpt]:
      last = midpt - 1
    else:
      first = midpt + 1

  return False
```